# iOS 11/Xcode 9: UITableViewCell white background flickers on delete

Tags: uitableview, ios11, xcode9

On iOS 11 device on deleting a UITableViewCell unexpected white background appears for some reason however all background colors are set to blue in storyboard (works fine on iOS10).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.bookmarks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];            
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Tried all types of **UITableViewRowAnimation**, doesn't solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: I too am having this problem. Setting cell's `backgroundView` to a view with a non-white background has no effect.

Comment: I've already played around tableView' and cell's views (contentVieц/accessoryView) background/tint colors with no effect...

Comment: Should a bug be filed with Apple for this issue?

Comment: I've already submitted a bug report, nothing is heard from apple so far

Comment: Would you mind posting a link to the report?

Comment: bug reports are private and i'm not an openradar fan, here is link to apple forum https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/266815

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @DianaProdan Nope, temporary changed app color scheme to white so the issue is not visible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try it (you can choose appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses instead).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ...

    [[UITableViewCell appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I confirmed that it has been fixed this problem on simulator.

Comment: Yep, i've set all background colors to clear (except tableView.backgroundColor which is still blue one) and implemented the proxy as you suggesting - it works! Thank you!

Comment: It works! Swift 4: `UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear`

Comment: Not an elegant solution but it's the only thing that works.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything that's possible and only thing that work was

adding

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: Make sure all elements have a transparent background color or the light blue you are using. Apparently there is one that still has a white background color, could be the cell content view (if you have one) or the cell background.